# How can I do something within the controller at the end of the request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate

I want to dispose the NHibernate Session object at the end of the controller request, that is, after rendering the view and all. Where should I do it?

Comment: We would need to know how you're starting it first. Generally wrapping any datacontext in a using will ensure it's disposed, but if you are using other IOC containers and binding your session "start" to something else, then there's a very different solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own [custom action filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609.aspx) and override [OnResultExecuted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.onresultexecuted.aspx).

Just for reacting at the end of the controller request, don't know much about NHibernate.

EDIT: And as mentioned from jgauffin you can also override OnResultExecuted in your controller as well.

Comment: +1 You should also mention that it's also possible to override `OnResultExecuted` in the controller (since he likely have a member field in the controller)

Comment: Yep, you're right, but I thought about a solution where he can put the attribute to all his controllers. But we both don't know how his code looks like :) Thanks for your addition.

Answer (score 0):

Its not your controller responsibility to dispose your NHibernate session. Ideally it would need to be your repository or/and your IoCContainer when disposing your repository.
Same as the answer above don't know much about NHibernate but that's the sort of pattern I would follow.

Answer (score 0):

A long post, but I do something along the lines of:-

In my global.asax.cs

```
public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; set; }
```

and then define in app start

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    var nhConfig = new Configuration().Configure();
    SessionFactory = nhConfig.BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

This class is then created:-

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class NHSession : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public NHSession()
    {
        Order = 100;
    }

    protected ISessionFactory sessionFactory
    {
        get
        {
                return MvcApplication.SessionFactory;
        }
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
        session.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var session = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(sessionFactory);
        if (session != null)
        {
            if (session.Transaction.IsActive)
            {
                try
                {
                    session.Transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch
                {
                    session.Transaction.Rollback();
                }
            }
            session.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Then my generic repository looks something along the lines of:-

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    private readonly ISessionFactory SessionFactory;
    public Repository(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        SessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
    public ISession Session
    {
        get
        {
            return SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
        }
    }
    public T Get(long id)
    {
        return Session.Get<T>(id);
    }
}
```

My concrete implementation of a repository is:-

```
public class CmsContentRepository : Repository<CmsContent>, ICmsContentRepository
{
    public CmsContentRepository(ISessionFactory sessionFactory) : base(sessionFactory) { }
}
```

And one more thing I then decorate my controllers like so:-

```
[NHSession]
public ViewResult Revisions(int id)
{
    var model = Service.CmsContentRepository.Get(id);
    return View("Revisions", model);
}
```

This then gives me the ability to use a unit of work across a request. Basically a request comes in and starts a session, the sessionfactory is passed into the ctor of the repository(ies)... I do use DI here but that is optional. If an error is detected then the session is rolled back if not it is committed on the end of a request. I would recommend NHProf as it helps you understand with session management (that is if it is not set up correctly).